# Having issue with Random Number generation in javascript

Tags: javascript, random, titanium-modules

I am build an app in javascript language. I am generating the random number with specified rates. E.g. If I have setted the rate 80 means in 1 minutes 80 random numbers will generate. 
I am using the following code to do this.

```
var player = Ti.Media.createSound({
    url : "sound.aiff"
});

var randomfunc = function() {
    randomno = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99);
    player.play();
    d_label1.text = randomno;
};

var start_fun = function(rate1) {

    start_btn.title = "Stop";

    waittime = rate1 * 1000;
    generate = false;
    stoptime = setInterval(randomfunc, waittime);

};

//------------------------------- function which stops displaying rendom numbers-------------------------

Ti.App.stop_fun1 = function() {
    start_btn.title = "Start";
    generate = true;
    clearInterval(stoptime);
    d_label1.text = "00";

};

start_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (generate == true) {
        rate = rate / 60;
        rate = 1 / rate;
        start_fun(rate);

    } else if ( generate == false) {
        Ti.App.stop_fun1();

    }

});
```

So, when I press the start button the generation of numbers start according to as required. After generating the numbers. When for second time I press start button the numbers dont generate. But for the third time again press numbers starts generation of number. 
Similarly 4th, 6th etc. time numbers wont generate but they will generate perfectly for 1st, 3rd, 5th etc. time. 
Why after every 2nd time numbers don't generate?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is designed to work this way.

You have an event listener that listens for clicks on an element. It then tests for a condition (generate) if this is true then it starts the counter in start_fun. However, start_fun also sets generate to false. The next time the button is clicked, it checks generate, see it is false and runs stop_fun which sets it back to true (but won't run start_fun). What you need to do is to set it back to true in start_fun After the count down has happened.

You click start_btn, generate is set to true (lets say)

if(generate == true) is correct so start_fun is called. This sets generate to false.

You click start_btn again

this time generate == false so stop_fun is executed. This means no numbers are generated but generate is set to true again.

you click start_btn and generate is set to true, so start_fun runs etc etc.

Comment: I just missed this thing while posting the question in the code I have double equal sign. So, that is not the issue... Thanks

Comment: I have added in a new answer as I now see the problem. It's a logic problem.

Comment: Ok. I got your point and I did set the generate to true after countdown happened. But that didn't solve issue. Or may be I am not correcting the error well can you please paste the modified code ?? Thanks

Comment: can you please further guide. I did what you said but that didn't work. Can you please if possible paste the corrected code. I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Hello Nadeem, when I get home tonight I will look into this further and try and assist you.

Comment: Thanks Looking forward to it.

Comment: Hi BenM I am still looking for your answer. I have tried myself but couldn't get through the error.  Please help me I will really be greatful to you.

Comment: Hello Nadeem. I have been unable to fix this easily. I think you may need to ask someone more experienced for help with this problem or attempt to rewrite the code in a different fashion.